# Trying to read a .txt file then return it to a List within a function to be called upon

Tags: list, file, python-3.x, text

I'm trying to get a file to be read and returned within a new list, but I can't quite seem to get it to work without errors. I'm very new to the coding scene so I apologize if I am lacking anything.

```
def FindMovieRatings (list2):
      list2=[]
      movie= open("movieData.txt", "r")
      list2.append (movie)
      return (list2)
```

It's also suppose to be a simple list append.

Comment: While Python can do a lot for you under the hood, there are some things it still needs to be told. When you `open`, it's returning a file-like object, but not the actual contents of that object. You then need to `read` from the `file`. something like `data = movie.read()` and then `list2.append(data)`. I don't think this is 100% what you want, but it should get you started

Comment: Thank you, any help is much appreciated and I'll give it a shot anyway. Thank you again.

Comment: Using the python itnerpreter interactively can help a lot. running `help(movie)` would tell you what type of object it is and some other information about how to use it; `print(movie)` would show that it's not the text but some other object.